# Lambdas Python for loop

Tags: python, lambda

I wanted to use lambdas inside for loops to return if certain elements are non-numerical:

```
strs = ['1234', 'hello', '6787']
```

I can use a `for` loop and iterate through each element:

```
for elem in strs:
```

and check `elem.islpha()`.

However, is there a way to use `lambdas` coupled with a `for` loop to return the word `"hello"`?

Comment: So it sounds like you have a working solution. Why do you want to use `lambda` expressions? It isn't needed and won't provide anything over a list comprehension, normal for loop, etc.

Comment: Just for interest, I wanted to understand

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this, it's easy using a list comprehension:

```
lst =  ['1234', 'hello', '6787']
[x for x in lst if x.isalpha()]
=>  ['hello']
```

Or if you definitely want to use a lambda:

```
filter(lambda x: x.isalpha(), lst)
=>  ['hello']
```

Notice that you'll rarely use lambdas for filtering inside a `for` loop, it's not idiomatic. The way to go for filtering elements out of a list is using list comprehensions, generator expressions or (less recommended) the `filter()` built-in function.

Comment: Suppose, my list was `list = [u'\n', u'test', u'\t']` would I need to convert the list entries to strings and then check `.isalpha()`?

Comment: I think if there is space in `test` to `test and some stuff` `.isalpha()` breaks down

Comment: @MaxKim then you should check if `not x.is_number()`, use the function defined in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-in-python)

Comment: Or, could I do x.strip().isalpha()?

Comment: @MaxKim or even better, make sure that your list doesn't contain spaces in the first place. Use [`split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) in the input string

Comment: 2 ways: `''.join(x.split()).isalpha()` (not sure if this works) and `x.replace(' ','').isalpha()` (this works)

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, become accustomed to list comprehensions:

```
>>> strs = ['1234', 'hello', '6787']
>>> [s for s in strs if s.isalpha()]
['hello']
```

They are the most adaptable and in most cases, the most readable way of doing this. Then why would you use `map`? `map` is fast and good looking for simple cases:

```
>>> map(str.upper, strs)
['1234', 'HELLO', '6787']
```

But **the instance you have to use `lambda`**, map becomes **ugly** and **slow**. This rule also applies for `filter`.

```
In [1]: strs = ['1234', 'hello', '6787']

In [2]: %timeit map(lambda s: s[0] if s.isalpha() else s, strs)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.48 us per loop

In [3]: %timeit [s[0] if s.isalpha() else s for s in strs]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 799 ns per loop
```

Many people have suggested

```
>>> filter(lambda s: s.isalpha(), strs)
['hello']
```

But remember `lambda s: s.isalpha()` is just fluff for `str.isalpha`, the method of the string class.

```
>>> filter(str.isalpha, strs)
['hello']
```

This makes it clean and fast to use `filter` here, but remember the consequences once you involve `lambda`s.

**Implementation detail of Python 2.x**

Unfortunately python 2.x has two different string types (In python 3 there is only `str` which is unicode) `str` and `unicode`. Therefore the clean solution using `str.isalpha` won't work. You could simply change this to `unicode.isalpha` but if you are mixing `unicode` and `str` you need something cross compatible.

One alternative is to use `methodcaller`

```
>>> strs = [u'\n', u'test', u'\t']
>>> from operator import methodcaller
>>> filter(methodcaller('isalpha'), strs)
[u'test']
```

But this isn't very straightforward, that's why it's nice to just use list comprehensions to avoid this trouble.

```
>>> [s for s in strs if s.isalpha()]
[u'test']
```

Comment: (1) `str.isalpha` doesn't return an uppercase copy, that's `str.upper`. :^)  (2) `str.isalpha` won't work if the OP has Python 2 unicode strings as suggested in his comment (`[u'\n', u'test', u'\t']`).

Comment: @DSM I fixed (1), didn't see `2`, I will add that to my answer

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to use `lambda`, or you are learning functional programming, you can use `filter`:

```
>>> filter(lambda x:x.isalpha(), ['123','hello','456'])
['hello']
```

Using lambda inside a loop makes no sense in your context, since you can call `x.isalpha()` directly

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you're looking for. You can't use a `for` loop explicitly, but you can use a generator expression:

```
check_isalpha = lambda lst: (elem for elem in lst if elem.isalpha())[0]
```

Comment: That's a list comprehension, not a generator expression.

Comment: @Anorov I had it as a generator originally :P I'll change it back, though.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to pull non-numerical items from a list, I don't see the need to use a lambda.

```
alphas = [item for item in strs if item.isalpha()]
```